# Rubymonk Ascent lesson: "Ripping the Guts"

Tags: ruby

From the Rubymonk ascent tutorial "[Ripping the Guts](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/33-advanced-arrays/lessons/76-ripping-the-guts#solution4111)", what's the difference between this code: (mine)

```
# compute([[4, 8], [15, 16]])

def compute(ary)
  return nil unless ary
  ary.map do |a, b| 
    a + b unless b.nil?
    a if b.nil?
  end
end
```

and the solution given:

```
def compute(ary)
  return nil unless ary
  ary.map { |(a, b)| !b.nil? ? a + b : a }
end
```

My code doesn't pass the tests, but the solution does. They look like they do the same thing though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `b.nil?` is false, then the following line:

```
a if b.nil?
```

Evaluates to `nil`. Since this is the last statement in the block, this is the value that is returned from your block. It doesn't see the `nil` and return the previous line's value instead, or completely "skip over" the line since the `if` wasn't true, it just returns `nil`.

If you were interested in *doing* something instead of *returning* a value, then I think your code would do the same thing as the given solution. The statements `a` and `a + b` aren't evaluated unless they're the result you're interested in (which would be important if they were method calls doing something external).

Comment: In case it's not clear to the reader, the line  `a + b unless b.nil?` has no effect, as it doesn't assign a value and is not the last line executed.